# Displaying intellisense automatically (Visual C++ 2010 Express)

Tags: visual-c++, intellisense, visual-c++-2010-express

One thing that has always annoyed me in Visual C++ is the fact that, unlike Visual C#, intellisense does not automatically display when a new line (or equals sign, etc) is entered, so I must press Ctrl+Space every time.

Is there any way to change this? It has gotten to the point where I have even considered using something like AutoIt to detect when I press Enter and insert a Ctrl+Space accordingly. Obviously, that is far from ideal.

Has the Visual Studio crew really overlooked such a glaringly obvious mistake, or have I simply missed an option somewhere?

Comment: yeah, this is annoying, as far as I know there is know way to set the option to automatically display without hitting the keys.

Answer (score 0):

That is by design behavior on the part of C++ IntelliSense.  There is no option to change it.  Alternative behaviors are supported by 3rd party extensions like [Visual Assist X](http://www.wholetomato.com/), however express editions of Visual Studio do not support addins and tool extensions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, at least I now know that I didn't overlook some option somewhere.  All I found online was that C++ IntelliSense simply didn't work properly (due to technical limitations?), although I've never had much trouble with it.  These days I just use gEdit and GCC for programming, though.